# Show that $\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2+1}+\frac{1}{c^2+a^2+1}\leq 1$.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Let $a, b, c>0$ s.t. $abc (a+b+c)=3$.

Show that $\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2+1}+ \frac{1}{c^2+a^2+1}\leq 1$.

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: In the worst case you could just multiply both sides by $$(a^2 + b^2 + 1)(b^2 + c^2 + 1)(a^2 + c^2 + 1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2+c^2}{(a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Any hint about how to prove $ab+bc+ca \geq 3$?

Comment: @cr001 Use homogenization.

Comment: Thank you. I finally found out this boils down to the fact $abc\leq 1 \implies abc \leq ^3\sqrt{abc}$. Anyway thank for the advice and I was able to convince myself $ab+bc+ca\geq 3$ is indeed true.

Comment: @cr001 1 I think $abc\leq1$ leads to the wrong inequality. The homogenization gives something right.

Comment: I just realized what I found out was indeed wrong. A very interesting problem, I will try more to figure this out.

Comment: I am ready to show. Say only.

Comment: I think I figured out the homogenization method. Basically first square $ab+bc+ca$ and expand the expression out. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we have $abc(a+b+c)=3$, which means that the known inequality $abc \le \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{27}$ gives $\frac{3}{a+b+c}\le\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{27}$, giving further $a+b+c \ge 3$.

And, therefore, $abc = \frac{3}{a+b+c} \le 1$, which we shall call inequality (1)

We know $ \sum_{cyc}{a^2} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3} \ge 3 $, which we shall call inequality (2)

Making it such that you have the same denominator everywhere, the inequality will become equivalent to
$$2 \sum {a^2} +2 \le \sum {a^2b^2(a^2+b^2)} + 2a^2b^2c^2 $$ 
$$\text {or, equivalently,}$$ $$2 \sum_{cyc} {a^2} +2 + a^2b^2c^2 \le (\sum_{cyc}{a^2})(\sum_{cyc} {(ab)^2})   $$ which is true since,$$\text{ by} \sum_{cyc}{x^2} \ge \sum_{cyc}{xy} \text{ applied for the last cyclical sum, where } (x,y,z)=(ab,bc,ac) \text{ we have}$$
$$\sum_{cyc}{a^2}\sum_{cyc}{(ab)^2} \ge (\sum_{cyc}{a^2})[abc(a+b+c)] = 3\sum_{cyc}{a^2} = 2\sum_{cyc}{a^2} + \sum_{cyc}{a^2} \ge $$ $$ 2\sum_{cyc}{a^2}+3 \ge 2\sum_{cyc}{a^2}+ 2 + a^2b^2c^2 $$ The two last steps were made using inequality (1), respectively (2), which we know to be true. Q.E.D.

Comment: I think you made a mistake during expanding.

Comment: Edited it so that it is correct, I hope no mistakes have been made now.

Comment: Now it's true. +1.